# Check whether number is float with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to check if number is float with Zend. If I invoke this code:

```
Zend_Locale_Format::isFloat('4.202', array('locale' => 'de'));
```

it returns true. However, this:

```
Zend_Locale_Format::isFloat('4.20', array('locale' => 'de'));
```

returns false. Why?

Comment: Does German locale use period for thousand separators?

Comment: whats wrong with `is_float()`?

Comment: please specify operating system and  ZF version and PHP version

Comment: @Jacco `is_float()` is not locale sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because German locale uses the period `.` as the thousand separator, and in your second example that separator is in the wrong place.

For example:

```
13.001,45
```

Should give the expected `true` when passed to `isFloat()`.

Btw, `4.202` gets interpreted as `4202` (which could also be considered a float without a fraction).

See also: [Normalization and Localization](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.locale.parsing.html), section "29.3.6. Floating point value testing"

Comment: Would the first one be expected to return true then?  What's the diff. between the `isInteger` and `isFloat` methods I wonder?

Comment: @ficuscr Yes, the first is simply `4202` but with a thousand separator; and an integer can be considered as float as well.

Comment: if an integer can be considered a float as well, you could as well test for 'isNumber'. Normally, 'float' and 'integer' in computer languages (including PHP) refer to the (distinct) basic datatypes.

Comment: @Jacco I didn't write the Zend framework; for some reason they felt compelled to call the method `isFloat()` ... like how would a person on the street write a number with fraction?